# Oracle data types variations

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I'm a new beginner to Oracle ,I'm so confused about the data types .

---

I don't know the difference between :

- `INT`,`INTEGER`,`NUMBER`
- `CHAR`,`CHAR VARYING` ,`CHARACTER`,`CHARACTER VARYING`

Comment: Do you really want an answer that is pure Oracle documentation?

Comment: Check this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/olap.102/b14346/dml_datatypes002.htm#CJACDECG

Comment: i read the doc but still confused about the difference , because when i create column with datatype `integer` it converted to `NUMBER(38)`!!

Comment: Please ask specific question. Show your code, so we can reproduce your case, and be able to provide accurate answer. Avoid **[XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer datatype is now deprecated and it is equivalent to NUMBER(38,0). The keyword is retained for compatibility.

Also you can check the [Oracle PL/SQL book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=iWhbFeboD84C&pg=PA194&lpg=PA194&dq=CHAR%20VARYING%20%20in%20oracle&source=bl&ots=yzukPc-3BD&sig=NpV5ApDqHuiGnoawQMWXlqz7I-Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKlqnth5XKAhVBdXIKHRF7Cz0Q6AEIJDAC#v=onepage&q=CHAR%20VARYING%20%20in%20oracle&f=false)

[image]

Comment: Could you illustrate the difference between `INTEGER` vs `INT`.AND `CHAR` vs `CHARACTER` vs `CHAR VARYING` vs `CHARACTER VARYING`

Comment: @just_name:- INTEGER and INT are equivalent. Similarly CHAR and CHARACTER are equivalent. And so for CHAR VARYING vs CHARACTER VARYING

Comment: Then if i want to use `float` should i use `NUMBER` also ?!

Comment: @just_name:- It depends as to how much precision you are looking for. There is a float datatype as well which is an alias for a REAL or DOUBLE PRECISION data type. And the default precision for float is 53.